# Как правильно написать на python запрос к pinterest?

Tags: python, requests

Запрос к pinterest /get;post/ без использования дополнительных библиотек

Comment: Без дополнительных - сомнительно, но могу сказать, что это делается обычно так: `import requests; requests.get(url)`, либо post() вместо get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для взаимодействия с Pinterest необходимо зарегистрировать свое приложение. Более подробно - [документация](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/?)

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'http://some.url')
r = http.request('POST', 'http://some.url')
```